# Thinktecture Identity Server v2 using ASP.NET identity v2

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, asp.net-identity-2

I have already tried to use out of box of ASP.NET membership provider and MembershipReboot.

but I also would like to know is there any way that I can integrate ASP.NET Identity V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same extensibility points that both Membership and MembershipReboot use to support ASP.NET Identity.